# How to access .dtsx file in SQL Agent job step in SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-agent-job

In SQL Server Management Studio, under SQL Server Agent, Jobs folder, I double-click a job.  This opens the Job Properties window.  Then I go to Steps, and double-click the first step of the job.  This opens the Job Step Properties window as below:

[image]

In the Package textbox is a path to a .dtsx file.  The path is similar to \SSISDB\...\Step1Package.dtsx

Where is this .dtsx file located on the SQL server?  And how can I view the file?  Can I use Visual Studio 2017 to view the .dtsx file?

Comment: It's in the SSIS catalog. Take a look at "exporting an SSIS package in managent studio" https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1428/import-export-copy-and-delete-ssis-packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the package source. It says `SSIS Catalog`. You'll find your package at below location:

`Integration Services Catalogs -> SSISDB -> <your package path>`

[image: ssdb location]

The reason being, you've deployed the SSIS solution as [Project Deployment Mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2450/ssis-project-deployment-model-in-sql-server-2012-part-1-of-2/)

Additional info : [Microsoft document on SSIS deployment mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

one way to view the package in visual studio is as follows:

Step 1. 
Open a integration services project in visual studio

Step 2. 
Add a existing package in the solution explorer
[image]
Step 3.
Select SQL server and type in the adress of the SSISserver where your package is located. Then click on the dots on right side of the screen and select the package path. 
[image]